# Posting/editing subject to unpredictable lag

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, api

I've noticed recently (in the past few days), there's occasionally a confusing lag when posting comments in the Android app. I haven't updated the app in forever though, so I don't think it's the app itself having problems. It's highly inconsistent though. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't.

I'll post a comment, it will show, then when I go back in to the question, my comment has "disappeared" for awhile, then "reappears" a minute or so later. It seems like the app shows my recently posted comment while waiting for a response from the API, then for some reason the API has a delay in reporting the comment being posted, so it disappears, then finally registers the comment and it appears again.

The same behavior happens with editing comments too unfortunately. I'll make an edit to a comment and post it. Then, if I make a second edit before the first "has gone through", the first edit will be discarded.

I'm not sure if this is related to the app, or lag in the API. I almost exclusively use the Android app to use SO, and don't use the API for anything else. I did spend some time on the full site yesterday though, and I didn't notice any posting lag. I'm also not sure if this is exclusive to comments, or if it extends to questions and/or answers as well. I haven't had issues with either of those.

---

Update:

It's now happening for the vote and acceptance of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51014699/3000206) answer. It's showing that I haven't voted on or accepted the answer even though I have. When I try to vote or accept it though, I get the "you've already done that" messages.

Comment: The app is old by now, and 100% unmaintained. It's totally expected to get such problems, which will only get worse with time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've been using the same version forever though and never had this problem. I don't see why an unchanging app would suddenly change behavior without some external cause.

Comment: We can't really know... But like an old car without any maintenance it's ought to fall apart slowly but surely. My point is, while valid bug report, don't expect any official response or a fix to ever come.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think that analogy really holds. And this was more of a note regarding the API, which is why I tagged the API, and not the app.

Comment: The Android app and the public API are not the same. But I coulda swore I saw a similar report about the public API, just can't find it at the moment...  Pretty sure the "lag" was not "unpredictable", but rather the grace period.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles The app uses the public API afaik.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the app uses a private privileged API that has some overlap with the public API.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Oh. I thought the reason why we can't see deleted posts was because that isn't accessible via the public API. Oh well.